# PHP how to extract info from json string wtihout knowing the keys

Tags: php, json

I am querying a service if a person have phone number(s) (also maybe not). I have a json string (as return value) like the following:

```
$json = '{"data":[{"tel1":"1102"},{"tel2":"3220"}],"found":true}';
```

I convert this string to `json_decode()` function.

```
$jd = json_decode($json);
```

Then I want to get the phone numbers only into an array without keys.

```
if($jd->found) {
    $o2a = get_object_vars($json);

}
var_dump($o2a);
```

When I want to see what `$o2a` holds with `var_dump()` function, I get the following:

```
array (size=2)
    'data' => 
        array (size=2)
            0 => 
                object(stdClass)[2]
                public 'tel1' => string '1219' (length=4)
            1 => 
                object(stdClass)[3]
                public 'tel2' => string '2710' (length=4)
    'found' => boolean true
```

I want to get only the phone numbers into an array at the end like:

```
$phones = array('1219', '2710');
```

What makes me stop doing this is that I do not know how many phone numbers one can have. Json array could consist of more or less elements.

```
$possibleJson1 = '{"data":[],"found":false}'; //no phone number found
$possibleJson2 = '{"data":[{"tel1":"1102"},{"tel2":"3220"},{"tel3":"1112"},{"tel4":"3230"}],"found":true}'; //4 phone numbers found
```

It may vary `0`-to-`n`, so if it was a constant number I could create that array within a loop.

Comment: If you pass `true` for the second parameter (`json_decode($json, true);`), it'll decode JavaScript objects to an associative array that you can iterate more easily.

Comment: You don't need to know the exact number, like in other languages... In PHP you can use a foreach-loop on the `data`-key given, that it only contains phone numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some functions without any code :)

```
$json = '{"data":[{"tel1":"1102"},{"tel2":"3220"}],"found":true}';

$vals = array_values(array_reduce(json_decode($json, true)['data'], 'array_merge',[]));
var_dump($vals);
```

Comment: **Notice:** `Use of undefined constant array_merge - assumed 'array_merge'`

Answer (score 2):

Convert it into an array and then you should be able to iterate it easily

```
$jd = json_decode($json, true);
$phones = array();
if(isset($jd['data']) && $jd['found']) {
    foreach($jd['data'] as $key => $val) $phones[] = $val;
}
```

Comment: This also works well but I chose @splash58's answer because it has not loop

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of handling with an object, use the second parameter of the `json_decode` function so it would returned an array.
- Check if the `data` and `found` keys exist.
- Since you don't know what are the keys names, you can use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)
- [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d07f5ad637e7a440a149190518780fe22c8f28c)

.

```
$jd = json_decode($json, true);
if(isset($jd['data']) && isset($jd['found'])){
  $telArr = $jd['data'];

  $phones = array();
  foreach($telArr as $tel){
    $value = array_values($tel);
    $phones[] = $value[0];
  }

  var_dump($phones);
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "1102"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "3220"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would try something like that:

```
$json = '{"data":[{"tel1":"1102"},{"tel2":"3220"}],"found":true}';
$jd = json_decode($json);
$phones = [];

if ($jd->found && count($jd->data)) {
    foreach ($jd->data as $key -> $value) {
        $phones[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as using `in_array` and simple `foreach` loop

```
$json = '{"data":[{"tel1":"1102"},{"tel2":"3220"}],"found":true}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$result = array();
if (in_array(true, $arr)) {
    foreach ($arr['data'] as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $k => $v)
            $result[] = $v;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/386159)